# Set state in React Hooks produce a loop

Tags: reactjs, loops, react-hooks, setstate

Hello I am using React/Hooks. This is my code to update the variable dataReg

```js
const [dataReg, setDataReg] = useState([])
const readReg = async () => {
  const data = await readRecord(var)
  setDataReg(data)
}

useEffect(() =>
  readReg()
  console.log(dataReg)
},[dataReg])
```

The value is updated correctly but it produces a loop in the console, showing the value of dataReg. What is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You have an extra closing brace (first character on the last line)

Comment: what are you trying to do? your useEffect function runs everytime dataReg changes and inside the function you again change dataReg.

Comment: It worked adding a second useEffect as @cyntler suggested

Answer (score 0):

You loop is started at:

```js
useEffect(() =>
  readReg()
  console.log(dataReg)
},[dataReg])
```

it runs `readReg()` which finally call `setDataReg()` and "reference" to the dataReg is changed.

The result of that is your useEffect runs again and again readReg()... loop.
You have to make something different to stop this loop.

Maybe `[]` instead of `[dataReg]` as a second parameter of useEffect would be enough.

Comment: thanks for you answer. When the second parameter of useEffect is just [ ], dataReg is empty.

Comment: @RanuCastaneda so you can add the second one useEffect with [dataReg] and check by `if` - if (dataReg) { // make something }